# Calculating formdata encoding OVERHEAD - multipart/form-data ( RFC 2388 )

Tags: javascript, html

When a 3 byte string "ABC" is encoded according to **[RFC 2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html)** ( `multipart/form-data` ) the `formdata` that is sent by e.g. `XMLHttpRequest` is much larger than the 3 bytes due to the encoding [overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)#Encodings_and_data_structures_(size_overhead)).

Also, when a 100 byte file is encoded as `formdata` ( `multipart/form-data` ) the amount of bytes actually sent is approximately 300 bytes, due to the encoding [overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)#Encodings_and_data_structures_(size_overhead)).
This is normal because the headers and delimiters of key/value pairs of this encoding take space, as well as the filename, etc...

**QUESTION**: How to calculate this encoding size [overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)#Encodings_and_data_structures_(size_overhead)) when `formdata.size` is not defined?

Below is my attempt to calculate this overhead by subtracting the sum of the *raw objects sizes*, which are contained inside the `formdata`, from the size of the entire [RFC 2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) encoded `formdata` itself.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input name=a>
  <input type=file name=b>
  <button type="Button" onclick="clickMe()" name="Button"> Calculate Overhead </button>
</form>
```

,

```
function SumOfObjects(formdata) {
  var size = 0;
  for(var pair of formdata.entries()) {  
    if (pair[1] instanceof Blob) 
      size += pair[1].size;
    else
      size += pair[1].length;
  }

  return size;
}

function clickMe() {
  var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));

  alert("Bytes taken by all raw objects= " + SumOfObjects(formdata) );
  alert("Bytes taken by the encoded formdata= " + formdata.size); //encoded as multipart/form-data (RFC 2388) - DOES NOT WORK !
  alert("Bytes of encoding Overhead= " + formdata.size - SumOfObjects(formdata) );
}
```

Comment: No, there's no such mechanism on client side within my eyesight. It should meet your requirements by using Blob/BufferSource alternatively.  FormData encapsulates data in key/value format which always incurs some "overheads" out of ***your*** expectation.

Comment: the `ProgressEvent` of `XMLHttpRequest` contains a read-only property named `total`, which seems to contain the size of the encoded `formdata`, ...however it is impossible to have this event invoked without actually sending the data.